# WooCommerce specific product disable for specific user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, product

I want to disable a product for a specific user. I have three products, after buying one product of those need to disable other two products. How can I achieve this?

```
function remove_product_description_add_cart_button(){
    global $product;
    $category = 'categoryslug';
    if ( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', 12345 ) )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

}
add_action('wp','remove_product_description_add_cart_button');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Use user meta
2)Save something to it on purchase
3)On add to cart button code add if/else logic which checks if current user meta field has a value.